# R CMD check note: Found no calls to: ‘R_registerRoutines’, ‘R_useDynamicSymbols’

Tags: r, compilation, devtools

How to avoid the following NOTE that is appearing in `R CMD check` with the new R development version ( R Under development (unstable) (2017-02-15 r72179))?

```
• checking for unstated dependencies in examples ... OK
• checking line endings in C/C++/Fortran sources/headers ... OK
• checking compiled code ... NOTE
File ‘pkgname/libs/pkgname.so’:
  Found no calls to: ‘R_registerRoutines’, ‘R_useDynamicSymbols’

It is good practice to register native routines and to disable symbol
search.
```

For example in [Hmisc](https://www.r-project.org/nosvn/R.check/r-devel-macos-x86_64-clang/Hmisc-00check.html)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The message is somewhat arcane. I looked around also in other packages and I found that the `useDynLib(packagename)` in the NAMESPACE file was replaced by `useDynLib(packagename, .registration = TRUE)`.

In addition, I added a `.c` file, named `registerDynamicSymbol` in the `src/` directory with the following code:

```
// RegisteringDynamic Symbols

#include <R.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>
#include <R_ext/Rdynload.h>

void R_init_markovchain(DllInfo* info) {
  R_registerRoutines(info, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
  R_useDynamicSymbols(info, TRUE);
}
```

I took this suggestion from [GitHub Rcpp](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/issues/636).  The canonical reference is in [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Registering-native-routines)

Also [R Devel Mailinglist](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2017-February/073755.html) provided supplementary infos.

**UPDATE**

The most direct straightforward approach is:

1. use the current R Development Version (that will eventually become 3.4)
2. Run the `tools::package_native_routine_registration_skeleton(".")` and copy and paste the full output in a `packagename_init.c` file to be put in `src/`
3. update `NAMESPACE`, verifying that `useDynLib(packagename, .registration = TRUE)`
4. If necessary, replace the `exportPattern` with `export( list of object to be exported )`

**UPDATE 18th July**

As noted by @Symbolix using the most recent version of R and RStudio's devtools the point 2. (init.c files) appears handled by either devtools (using RStudio check digit) or tools packages.

Comment: I was am using `@useDynLib pkg fun` in the `devtools` package for registering C functions. [But it seems there is more to it.](https://www.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2001-3.pdf#section*.51)

Comment: I had the same problem - I used your suggestions and this is the result:   Found no call to: 'R_registerRoutines'
Which means it found the R_useDynamicSymbols statement. But I am wondering now, why the registerRoutines error did not disappear as well...

Comment: Shouldn't the fact that I am making my .C call with funtionname instead of  "functionName" and without package = "mypackage" indicate, that the registration actually worked...?

Comment: This was extremely helpful. The only problem I encountered was that devtools::release() wanted to re-write the NAMESPACE file during pre-release check, so losing the useDynLib edit. Setting check=FALSE when calling the release function fixed that.

Comment: I only needed steps 1 & 2 when building on R 3.4.0 (and also using NAMESPACE generated from roxygen)

Comment: @SymbolixAU, possibly the released R 3.4 has changed since dev version

Comment: For those working with roxygen, change your `@useDynLib packagename` to `@useDynLib packagename, .registration = TRUE`, so you don't need to manually edit the NAMESPACE file.

Comment: As of Rcpp 1.12.11 and R 3.4.0 I think this is all handled for you.

Comment: @SymbolixAU nope, just had the issue on my package with these versions :-(

Comment: For further ref, I got then error message: failed to assign RegisteredNativeSymbol for * to * since * is already defined in the * namespace. Just meant I had c routine and R wrapper with same name, so had to rename the C routine to different name, re-run process, and was good.

Comment: Make sure to indeed use R devel or R CMD; using e.g. devtools::check may still tell you "Found no calls to:..." even to you have added the above. See also http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Problem-with-R-registerRoutines-td4748507.html

Comment: If you get the error "no native symbols were extracted", try character_only: `tools::package_native_routine_registration_skeleton(".", "src/init.c", character_only=FALSE)`

Comment: I asked the R team, and they said that it is safe to ignore this note. (R version 4.1.2)

Answer (score 5):

I ran into a persistent issue with a Windows build package. (.dll instead of .so)

The accepted answer above should also resolve this issue for Windows, but if it does not resolve it. Make sure that `objdump.exe` is pointing the appropriate arch. i.e. `.../Mingw_64/bin/objdump.exe`. This can be checked from a command prompt with `which objdump.exe`. Somehow a 32-bit `objdump.exe` found its way into a higher priority position in my path. This arch mismatch will produce a `File format not recognized` error.

Answer (score 0):

First I did exactly what Giorgio Spedicato says. But still got NOTE warnings. Finally I got problem solved by doing this:

Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(Sys.getenv("PATH"),
"C:\RTools40",
"C:\RTools40\mingw64\bin",
sep = ";"))

Have to add mingw64\bin to PATH because that's where objdump.exe is located