# Registering routines for R package submission to cran

Tags: r, rstudio, packaging, cran, roxygen2

I'd like to submit an updated version of an R package ot cran but it's failing because of the note:

Found no calls to: ‘R_registerRoutines’, ‘R_useDynamicSymbols’

I tried the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42339658/3738150

Running `tools::package_native_routine_registration_skeleton(".")` yields

```
#include <stdlib.h> // for NULL
#include <R_ext/Rdynload.h>

/* FIXME:  
   Check these declarations against the C/Fortran source code.
*/

/* .C calls */ 
extern void rW(void *, void *, void *);
extern void ry_bing(void *, void *, void *);
extern void ry_bmf(void *, void *, void *, void *);

static const R_CMethodDef CEntries[] = {
    {"rW",      (DL_FUNC) &rW,      3},
    {"ry_bing", (DL_FUNC) &ry_bing, 3},
    {"ry_bmf",  (DL_FUNC) &ry_bmf,  4},
    {NULL, NULL, 0}
};

void R_init_rstiefel(DllInfo *dll)
{
   R_registerRoutines(dll, CEntries, NULL, NULL, NULL);
   R_useDynamicSymbols(dll, FALSE);
}
```

which I put in `rstiefel_init.c`

However, when I check this I get `Warning: failed to assign RegisteredNativeSymbol for rW to rW since rW is already defined in the ‘rstiefel’ namespace` etc for other definitions.

Any help wou'd be much appreciated!

The packaged I'd like to submit can be found at: https://github.com/pdhoff/rstiefel

Comment: I think the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Registering-native-routines) explains this very well, and that link is also mentioned in the question you referenced.

Comment: I've tried following the documentation as well to no avail.  A little more direction would be helpful.  Is there an example init file I can work from?

Comment: Plenty. I think I used [Rcpp](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/master/src/Rcpp_init.cpp)'s as initial reference. [Here's](https://github.com/asardaes/dtwclust/blob/master/src/init.cpp) one I use, which is simpler because I only use `.Call` functions.

Comment: The problem I keep having is "Warning: failed to assign RegisteredNativeSymbol for rW to rW since rW is already defined in the ‘rstiefel’ namespace".  I haven't seen any indication of why this happens or how to fix it.

Comment: I can't check your package right now, but I noticed your C file in the github repo doesn't include `R_ext/Rdynload.h`. I doubt that's the reason but just something I noticed.

Answer (score 1):

Your [R code](https://github.com/pdhoff/rstiefel/blob/master/R/rW.R) defines `rW <- ...`, but by registering a native routine with

```
{"rW",      (DL_FUNC) &rW,      3},
```

you're asking R to overwrite that symbol with a symbol representing the C-level function. You could instead register your routine with

```
{"C_rW",      (DL_FUNC) &rW,      3},
```

or when you indicate `useDynLib(..., .fixes = "C_")` in your NAMESPACE as indicated in [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#useDynLib).